# What is the appropriate listener to use for detecting movement/clicking in the text field of JDatePicker?

Tags: java, swing

In my GUI, I have a couple sets of radio buttons, each with two radio buttons. The first radio button is normal with the text, while the other one is only a radio button, and this has the JDatePicker next to it. I want to mimic the behavior of a radio button so that the JDatePicker appears to be coupled with it, so when it hovers over the JDatePicker's text field, the radio button lights up, and when it's clicked on the radio button changes to that field.

[image: GUI Screenshot]

I've made an action listener and added it to the JDatePickerImpl, and tried to listen for that component, but nothing happens-- the listener is not triggered when I click on the text field or button.

```
UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("text.today", "Today");
    p.put("text.month", "Month");
    p.put("text.year", "Year");
    JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model, p);
    // Don't know about the formatter, but there it is...
    fromDatePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel, new 
DateLabelFormatter());
    fromDatePicker.setBounds(45, 186, 170, 26);
    JFormattedTextField textField = 
fromDatePicker.getJFormattedTextField();
    textField.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));

nowRdBtn = new JRadioButton("Right This Second");
    nowRdBtn.setBounds(22, 235, 139, 29);
    buttonGroup_1.add(nowRdBtn);
    nowRdBtn.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));


TTListener listener = new TTListener();
    fromDatePicker.addActionListener(listener);


private class TTListener implements ActionListener {        
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == fromDatePicker) {
            System.out.print("Done");
            beginningRdBtn.setEnabled(false);
            fromDateRdBtn.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Individually, the components work as intended, but the desired coupling behavior does not. Getting the corresponding JFormattedTextField from the JDatePickerImpl and listening for that instead also does not yield any results.

Comment: Usually the "coupled" component would be disabled. Then when you click on the radio button you enable the component and request focus on the component. That is you should not be allowed to enter data into the coupled component until you select the radio button.

Comment: Camickr, I mean that when I click on the component the radio button would become enabled. It wouldn't necessarily have to work the other way around. For example when you hover over a label next to most radio buttons, it becomes focused, and then when you click on the label the radio button becomes active without having clicked on the radio button itself. This is the same functionality I'd like for the JDatePicker.

Comment: That is my point. It SHOULD work the other way around. First you chose which option you want by clicking on the radio button. Then you enable any component related to the radio button. `when you hover over a label next to most radio buttons` - that label IS the text of the radio button. Your second radio button should also have text like "Select Time" so the user knows what they are selecting

Comment: Okay, I understand what you're getting at, and after thinking it over I agree with you, that does make the most sense from an accessibility standpoint. I'm going to shift things around to match this formatting. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `JDatePickerImpl` you use is `org.jdatepicker.impl.JDatePickerImpl`. Here the `ActionListener`s are fired only when user select a date. You should try adding a `MouseListener` and implement `mouseEntered()` and `mouseExited()`.